# Image decoder can not decode the image. Perhaps the image is damaged

Tags: c#, wpf

Crash error, but it does not reach the catch "Image decoder can not decode the image. Perhaps the image is damaged."

in code:

images_dynamic - List

```
try
{
    string path = images_dynamic[0];
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Action)(() =>
    {
    BitmapImage bitimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));// fly exception
    p_dynamic_image.Source = bitimage;
    }));
}
catch { }
```

http://depositfiles.com/files/cgmhkeebf  - this is file.

I need that that would fly in to catch